# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''

Tags: php, sintaxe

Quero imprimir o valor na tela depois do resultado do PHP.

```
public function iniciar()
{
    $msg = '';
    $oneclick = null;
    # login...
    $this->login();

    if ($this->logado()) {
        $oneclick = $this->pegar_oneclick();


        $msg  ="$this->usuario $this->senha $oneclick['card']['cardNumber'] $oneclick['card']['holderName'] $oneclick['card']['expirationDate'] ");
        echo ('Logado - '.$msg);
    } else {
        $msg  = "$this->usuario:$this->senha";
         echo ('Não logado - '.$msg);
    }
}
}
```

Porém está me retornando o erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING) in

Comment: Em que linha está esse erro? (não aparece nada depois do `in`?)

Comment: $msg  = ("$this->usuario $this->senha $oneclick['card']['cardNumber'] $oneclick['card']['holderName'] $oneclick['card']['expirationDate']");
            echo ('Logado - '.$msg);

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 9):

Você não pode colocar expressões complexas dentro de *strings*. Prefira fazer concatenação de *string*:

```
$msg = $this->usuario . " " . $this->senha . " " . $oneclick['card']['cardNumber'] .
    " " . $oneclick['card']['holderName'] . " " . $oneclick['card']['expirationDate'];
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/Concatenation.php).

Ela parece produzir um texto ruim de ser lido mas pelo menos vai funcionar. Se não tiver outros erros que não podemos detectar.

Answer (score 7):

outra solução é especificar as variáveis

```
$msg  ="{$this->usuario} {$this->senha} {$oneclick['card']['cardNumber']} {$oneclick['card']['holderName']} {$oneclick['card']['expirationDate']} ";
//tava sobrando um ) no fim da string
```